# Links are not the right colors

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and I am unsure of why the links on the page are not showing up as the right colors when hovered over. Here is one of the pages: http://jsfiddle.net/yentup/CR9TK/

The links I am worried about are the links in the content of the page. When hovered over, they are supposed to be red. However, they stay the same color. I am able to force the correct color using `!important`, but I would much rather avoid this because then all the other links I also have to use `!important` on to get their correct colors as well. Here is the bit of css that is conflicting, but you can find all the css for the entire page in the link mentioned above:

```css
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #787878;
}

a:hover {
    color: #8B2323;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Quintessential', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #909090;
    border-left: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;
    padding: 8px 14px;
}

#header ul li a:hover {
    color: #D2691E;
}
```

Comment: They turn red for me in your Fiddle. Top ones are orange, middle one is Maroon.

Comment: Same for me, spent a little while looking for the 'important' in your CSS. What browser are you using?

Comment: They are working for me in your fiddle with Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: Your CSS looks fine. I think you have additional CSS that is overridding what you are doing. Open FireBug and see what styles are being applied and where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap places of `a:hover` and `a:visited` .

```
a:visited {
    color: #787878;
}

a:hover {
    color: #8B2323;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Should work then as expected.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the reason I wasn't seeing the color change is because I had already gone to the link. It works perfectly fine now ^_^

Comment: That's pretty stupid if that's the case but makes sense. Could you also do `a:hover, a:visited:hover` if you don't want to worry about the order? I don't like writing CSS that has to be ordered a certain way.